# Sampling with replacement: finding all answers with one specific characteristic

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I have a book, and I dont get it. We are talking about the following situation.Lets say you have 5 experiments and the sample space for each is $S = \{0,1\}$. So the total amount of possible outcomes is $2^5 = 32$. I get that. Next up, find all outcomes with exactly 3 ones in it. The outcomes are then given: ten in total. And then the following formula is given for finding out that there are exactly ten outcomes:
$$
{5 \choose 3} 
$$
Then everything gets generalized and, if the sample space $S$, there are $n$ subexperiments and you want to find out how many outcomes with $k$ ones there are, you do the following (given that $ k \leq n $):
$$
{n \choose k}
$$
But I dont get it. I can see that it is true by doing the counting and math on paper, but I cannot prove it. Why is this true? How do I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $5 \choose 3$ counts the number of ways to choose a subset of $3$ objects from a set of $5$. If you put the letters $A,B,C,D,E$ in a bag and draw three at random, you will get one of ${5 \choose 3} = 10$ outcomes ($ABC, ABD, \ldots, CDE$). Each of those outcomes can be associated with an experiment where the letters you picked correspond to $1$s:

```
ABC: 11100
ABD: 11010
...
CDE: 00111
```